# How to discover the method that is called by a Windows Context Menu item?

Tags: windows, winapi

When you click the right mouse button on your clean desktop it opens a context menu.
Each item there is a call to a method.
To programmatically call those methods, first I need to know which one I want.
IIRC there is a tool that helps with that, but I can't remember its name.

Comment: note that frameworks hide the low level details, so even if you use OOP, winapi uses messages underneath.

Comment: I think the tool you are looking for might be ShellExView (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call such a method in another process.  You could try to inject the WM_COMMAND message that a context menu usually generates with SendMessage.  Use Spy++ to find out what that message might be, if it exists.

Comment: It is impossible to use Spy++ drag'n'drop feature on context menus, because they close before when you try to use this tool

Comment: You want to spy on the window on which the menu is displayed.  That's the one that gets the command.

Answer (score 1):

Use Spy++ to find the handle and use SendMessage / PostMessage.  It will be something similar to:

```
hwnd = FindWindow(...)
hmenu = GetMenu(hwnd)
hsubmenu = GetSubMenu(hmenu, 0)
menuid = GetMenuItem(hsubmenu, 1)
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, menuid, 0)
```